# How to implement a function specific type in swift

Tags: swift, function, types

I want something like this:

```
enum ArgType { case Case1, case Case2 }
func foo(arg: ArgType) {
    // code
}
```

Above code works, but `ArgType` is only used for function `foo`, so I prefer it to be somehow "restricted" in function's scope, how should I do this?

---

```
func foo(arg: T) where T = enum _ { case Case1, case Case2 } {
    // code
}
// this doesn't compile, I put this here just for an example for what I want
```

Comment: I think the question is a little unclear, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AhmadF, sorry for that. Given the code in the question, I can write another function `bar(arg: ArgType)` because the `ArgType` is also visible to bar, I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot mark the Enum private and use it outside the class scope. If you want to encapsulate the enum, perhaps define it inside the scope of the class/struct.

```
struct Identifier {
    enum Cell {
        case Base
        case Home
    }

    func getIdentifier(identifier: Cell) -> String {
        return "An Identifier"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, encapsulating with class/struct/enum is a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

if it were restricted to the function. how would ppl call it? 
[im aware this is no answer]

**the answer is:** 
 there is no mechanic to restrict a type to function type only.
(maybe the function. is private and marking the type file private could help?)

Comment: The idea is like class specified types: I can declare a type `Foo` inside a class `Bar` and others can only refer to that type by typing `Bar.Foo` which explicitly indicates that the type `Foo` is meaningful in the context of `Bar`. Although making things private works, it can't satisfy my compulsion...